# Date from Thursday to last Thursday

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008, datediff

I am cracking my skull as to how to query records where the date field returns data from Thursday to the previous 7 days (Thursday). This is for reporting and I need assistance.

I had a look at the `DATEDIFF` function but not too sure how to have this date generic to run the SSRS report automatically.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, at least to me. Could you please share your table(s)'s structure, some sample data, and the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: select i.ticketnumber
from FilteredIncident i
where i.statecode = 1 and i.createdon...... my challenge is the function that will get me all Incidents where the createdon date is on a Thursday to past Thursday, so basically I want records that have a date of Today to last 7days , does this make sence?

Comment: Whether u required this in Expressions for SSRS (or) in Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM <TABLE_NAME> 
WHERE 
        <YOURDATE> >= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), -4) AND 
        <YOURDATE> <= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 3)
```

The code will select all the rows from the current Thursday to the previous Thursday.

DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), -4): Gives the date for the last Thursday
DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 3): Gives the date for the current Thursday

Answer (score 0):

For last 7 days something like that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tbl
WHERE YourDate BETWEEN (GETDATE() - 6) AND GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood from your question, here is one approach:

For this,you can make use of "between ... and" in SQL.

```
    SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE date 
BETWEEN DATE_SUB(your_date,INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND your_date;
```